# Roots of polynomial with integer coefficiants

Tags: python, polynomials

I have a polynomial with integer coefficients. The coefficients are very large(~200-300 digits). I need to find integer roots of this polynomial. I used numpy.roots() to find the roots, but the roots are not accurate. Sage does find the roots accurately. I am aware that there are algorithms to find integer roots of polynomials with integer coefficients. Is there implementation of such an algorithm in any python library which I can use directly? OR
How can I find integer roots of polynomial with integer coefficients in python?

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has a fairly [extensive](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) set of algorithms for root finding.  I am pretty sure they have robust error checking, so you might look there, first.

Comment: Ok. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

I am not a professional but i tried this.
(let me know if it works)

```
def roots(a,b,c):
    '''
     root Formula.
    '''
    r1=(-b+(b**2-4*a*c)**(1/2))/(2*a)
    r2=(b+(b**2-4*a*c)**(1/2))/(2*a)

    return r1,r2
```

call

```
result=roots(1,1,300)
print(result)
#gives result in form of tuple
```

thank you.

Comment: Sry. I should have mentioned it earlier. My polynomial is a degree-9 polynomial. So this will not work.

Comment: @kahcv okay i will try this also.